# Missing space between define and initializer sphynx rtd_theme

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using doxygen + breathe + Sphinx to document C source code.
In my conf.py I have set:

```
breathe_show_define_initializer = True
```

and

```
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
```

In my C source code I have defines such as:

```
 #define FOO 12U //!< example #define
```

In the xml generated from doxygen, I see:

```
       <name>FOO</name>
        <initializer>12U</initializer>
        <briefdescription>
<para>example #define </para>
        </briefdescription>
```

So far so good!

The problem is the output from Sphinx is missing white space between the name and the initializer.  i.e. as shown, no space between FOO and 12U:

```
FOO12U
example #define
```

I tried using both:

```
.. doxygendefine:: FOO
```

and I tried the group which has a number of defines:

```
.. doxygengroup:: MY_DEFINES_GROUP
```

If I change `html_theme = 'alabaster'`
Then there is a space between FOO and 12U

Any thoughts - am I missing a configuration?

Comment: Compare the HTML output of both themes. Are they identical? If so, then the issue is CSS, and you need to style the HTML according to your desires.

Comment: @StevePiercy - thank you.  I checked and the html is identical.  I'll look into changing the CSS (new area for me - any pointers are appreciated :) )

Comment: See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files for how to add a custom style sheet into which you can put your custom styles.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question via Google since I ran into the same issue. I'm posting my solution here which I hacked up and it seems to work for my case in the hopes of saving someone else time. My solution was to insert a "no break space" after each name of the define (but before the value).

1. Create a custom css: under _static/custom-signame.css (which is where I store my other custom css files)
2. The contents of the file are:

   ```
   /* add a space to fix Breathe+Sphinx rtd_theme with 
   breathe_show_define_initializer  */ 

   .sig-name::after { 
      content: "\00a0";
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that `conf.py` is updated to include the new custom css created in step 2:

   ```
   html_static_path = ['_static']
   html_css_files = [
       'custom-table.css',
       'custom-signame.css',
   ]
   ```